# Next JS server side rendering on Index.tsx with NextPage componet

Tags: next.js, sanity

tsx file having a Home component below it there is getServerSiderProps method.i want to get server side but props inside my Home component show undefined.

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Banner from '../Components/Banner'
import Header from '../Components/Header'
import Posts from '../Components/Posts'
import { sanityClient, urlFor } from '../sanity'

const Home: NextPage = ({ posts }) => {
  console.log(posts)
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Medium Blog</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Header></Header>
      <Banner></Banner>
      <Posts></Posts>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home

//Server Side Rendering (SSR)
export const getServerSiderProps = async () => {
  const query = `*[_type=="post"]{
    _id,
    title,
    slug,
    author->{
    name,
    image
  },
  description,
  mainImage,
  slug
  }`

  //Fetch
  const posts = await sanityClient.fetch(query)

  return { props: { posts } }
}
```

I want to get server side props every time it refresh my page but it became undefined.

Comment: Hi Shubam. If that's a direct copy-and-paste, you've got an extra `r` in `getServerSide*r*Props`. If that's actually correct in your code, perhaps confirm that your document is of type `post`.